# Need help: Something is not functioning right in my loop. I believe the result + result string is causing issues?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char

*I'm doing this specific exercise here:*
**Question:**
*Given a non-empty string and an int N, return the string made starting with char 0, and then every Nth char of the string. So if N is 3, use char 0, 3, 6, ... and so on. N is 1 or more.*
e.g:
**everyNth("Miracle", 2) → "Mrce"**

My code:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
  int a = 0; String result= ""; 

  for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) % n == 0) { 
      result = result + str.charAt(i);
    a++; 
  }  
 }
  return result;
}
```

I can't figure out how to fix my code given what my plan was:
1. Move result to String result
2. Run a loop and only move the data if modular = 0

But instead of getting **Mrce**, I'm getting *rl*
I don't need an easier solution, I just want to understand what is going on wrong and how to make it work.

Exercise Ref: https://codingbat.com/prob/p196441

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to advise you without telling you the answer, which is fairly simple. You want every nth character. So this,

```
if (str.charAt(i) % n == 0) {
```

should just be

```
if (i % n == 0) {
```

With just that change (and your provided input), I get (as expected)

```
Mrce
```

However, we **can** indeed make it easier by incrementing by `n` on each loop iteration. Thus eliminating the need for testing if `i` is divisible by `n`. We can also make the method `static`. And I would prefer a `StringBuilder`. Like,

```
public static String everyNth(String str, int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += n) {
        sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```